# Same routes in multiple resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, dry

I am working on a new rails application and came to this scenario. I want same routes in multiple resources but I don't want to repeat the same lines.

Is there any way to DRY up this

```
resources :contacts do
  collection do
    post :associate
    delete :remove
  end
end
resources :doctors do
  collection do
    post :associate
    delete :remove
  end
end
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
concern :associate do
  collection do
    post :associate
    delete :remove
  end
end

resources :contacts, :concerns => [:associate]
resources :doctors, :concerns => [:associate]
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for. I knew there is something but never got a chance to use this.